# Require field if other field exists

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

As part of this Flask-Restful Reqparse input schema I have an optional field `state`. If `state` exists then it should have required fields within it, such as `time`.

```
model_schema.add_argument(
    'state',
    type=dict
)
model_schema.add_argument(
    'time',
    type=float,
    required=True,
    location=('state')
)
```

The goal is `time` is required only if `state` exists.  If it doesn't exist then `time` doesn't matter, since I won't be using `state` at all.

The above example returns:

```
{"message": "[time]: Missing required parameter in state"}
```

How do I make this work?